# How to mimic Turing Machine description in Sipser textbook

Tags: lists, environments, enumerate

[Introduction to the Theory of Computation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/113318779X) by [Sipser](http://www-math.mit.edu/~sipser/) is one of the standard textbooks on theory of computation. To describe a [Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) (TM) in high level, this book uses a variant of enumeration lists in a very unique style. Let's look at the examples which I scanned from the textbook.

[image]

- The TM description begins with a machine name, which is usually an uppercase English letter.
- The machine name is followed by an equal sign and quotation marks.
- The first line of the description explains what an input is to the Turing machine.
- Then an enumeration list follows to give an actual high-level description of a TM.
- Sometimes, an indentation is required to indicate a *block* structure, as in step 2 and 3 in a TM *E* from 3.6 above.
- A TM description ends with a closing quotation mark.

[image]
* Sometimes, we need to reference a specific step in a TM description. For example in the above, stage 2, 3 and 5 points to a stage 1.

---

As a TA for this class, I want to copycat this structure for my class handout. What is the best way to mimic this TM description?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: why is 1. 2. 3. aligned with the open quote in 3.7 but indented under the n of `"Ignore` in 3.6?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think they're being aligned with a previous line.  I think it's just a rigid indentation, and, because of this, it looks inconsistent between the two examples given.

Comment: @A.Ellett perhaps. I'd align with the quote as that seems more logical (and easiest to implement:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{turing}[2]
 {\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt,labelsep=0pt,align=left,parsep=0pt]
  \item[$#1={}$]``\ignorespaces#2
  \begin{enumerate}[
    nosep,
    align=left,
    labelwidth=1.5em,
    label=\bfseries\arabic{*}.,
    ref=\arabic{*}
  ]}
 {\unskip''\end{enumerate}\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\bitem}{\item\hspace*{1em}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{turing}{E}{
  Ignore the input.
}
\item Repeat the following for $i=1,2,3,\dotsc$.
\bitem Run $M$ on $s_i$.
\bitem If it accepts, print out $s_i$.
\end{turing}

\begin{turing}{M_2}{
  On input string $w$:
}
\item Sweep left to right across the tape, crossing off every other \texttt{0}.\label{M2-sweep}
\item If in stage \ref{M2-sweep} the tape contained a single \texttt{0}, \emph{accept}.
\item If in stage \ref{M2-sweep} the tape contained more than a single \texttt{0}
  and the number of \texttt{0}s was odd, \emph{reject}.
\item Return the head to the left-hand end of the tape.
\item Go to stage \ref{M2-sweep}.
\end{turing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. I wonder if this template can be written to be more comfortable, requiring from the writer just to `\begin{turing} ... \end{turing}`

Comment: @johni I'm not sure what you have in mind simpler than this.

Comment: I see that this cannot have the `\begin{enumerate}` for inner enumerations. I do not have the knowledge for modifying your template to allow this. Could you please edit the template?

Comment: @johni That's a whole new question

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
E=\parbox[t]{.75\textwidth}{%
``Solve the halting problem, $H$:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{x}do these until something
\addtolength\itemindent{1em}
\addtolength\labelsep{1em}
\item check if it halts
\item try it
\addtolength\itemindent{-1em}
\addtolength\labelsep{-1em}
\item test if stopped, if not repeat step \ref{x}''
\end{enumerate}}
\]
\end{document}
```